# How to Convert scss to css

Tags: css, html, sass

Hello guys I found a html code and it uses scss.when I tried to convert it I had a lot of error can anyone convert it for me.I am a beginner in html and I have no idea on scss [this is the code from the website](http://codepen.io/tadaima/pen/rjvYab)

```
@function rndNumber($limit) {
  @return random($limit);
}

$globalSize: 400%;
$colorsList: ($white, $white, $white);
$bgDots: ();

$resultPosList: ();
$prevPosList: ();

$resultSizeList: ();
$prevSizeList: ();

$randomSize: 0;

@for $i from 1 through 16 {
    $thisColor: nth($colorsList, rndNumber(3));
    $bgDots: append($bgDots, radial-gradient($thisColor, $thisColor 70%, transparent 71%), 'comma');

    $resultPosList: append($resultPosList, (rndNumber(100) * 1%) (rndNumber(100) * 1%), 'comma');
    $prevPosList: append($prevPosList, 50% 50%, 'comma');

    $randomSize: rndNumber(3) * 2%;
    $resultSizeList: append($resultSizeList, $randomSize $randomSize, 'comma');
    $prevSizeList: append($prevSizeList, .25em .25em, 'comma');
}

.sparks {
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: $globalSize;
        height: $globalSize;

        background-image:       $bgDots;
        background-size:        $prevSizeList;
        background-position:    $prevPosList;
        background-repeat:      no-repeat;

        transition: all 0s ease-out;
        transition-delay:  0;
    }
}

.card {
    height: 15em;
    border-radius: 15em 15em 0 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba($white, .2);
}

.rating {
    &__label {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 1em;
        display: flex;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all $fastDuration ease-in-out;
        border: 1px solid rgba($white, .2);
        margin-left: -1px;
        &__icon {
            z-index: 2;
            transition: fill $fastDuration ease-in-out;
        }
        @for $i from 1 through 5 {
            &:nth-of-type(#{5-$i}) .rating__label__icon {
                transition-delay: ($fastDuration / 4) * $i;
            }
        }
    }
    &__background {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 3em;
        z-index: -1;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        transition: width $fastDuration $bezier;
        background-color: $white;
    }
    [type='radio'] {
        display: none;
    }
    &__fx {
        &--0 {
            perspective: 20em;
            .rating__label {
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                @for $i from 1 through 5 {
                    &:nth-of-type(#{5-$i}) {
                        transition-delay: ($fastDuration / 4) * $i;
                    }
                }
            }
            [type='radio'] {
                display: none;
                &:checked ~ .rating__label {
                    background-color: $white;
                    transform: rotateY(180deg);
                    .rating__label__icon {
                        fill: $coral;
                    }
                }
                &:first-of-type:checked + .rating__label:before {
                    background-size: $resultSizeList;
                    background-position: $resultPosList;
                    transition-duration:  $slowDuration;
                    transition-delay:  $fastDuration * 1.3;
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            }
        }
        &--1 {
            position: relative;
            @for $i from 1 through 24 {
                $thisColor: nth($colorsList, rndNumber(3));
                $bgDots: append($bgDots, radial-gradient($thisColor, $thisColor 70%, transparent 71%), 'comma');

                $resultPosList: append($resultPosList, (rndNumber(100) * 1%) (rndNumber(100) * 1%), 'comma');
                $prevPosList: append($prevPosList, 50% 50%, 'comma');

                $randomSize: rndNumber(3) * 2%;
                $resultSizeList: append($resultSizeList, $randomSize $randomSize, 'comma');
                $prevSizeList: append($prevSizeList, .25em .25em, 'comma');
            }
            .rating__label {
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                border-left-color: transparent;
                border-right-color: transparent;
                &:first-of-type {
                    border-radius: 0 3em 3em 0;
                    border-right-color: rgba($white, .2);
                    position: relative;
                }
                &:last-of-type {
                    border-radius: 3em 0 0 3em;
                    border-left-color: rgba($white, .2);
                }
            }
            [type='radio'] {
                display: none;
                @for $j from 5 through 1 {
                    &:nth-of-type(#{$j}):checked ~ {
                        .rating__label {
                            .rating__label__icon {
                                fill: $coral;
                            }
                        }
                        .rating__background {
                            $thisColor: hsl((340 - ($j * 20)), 56%, 66%);
                            $thisPos: 20% * (6 - $j);
                            // background-color: saturate($thisColor, 55%);
                            width: $thisPos;
                        }
                    }
                }
                &:first-of-type:checked + .rating__label:before {
                    background-size: $resultSizeList;
                    background-position: $resultPosList;
                    transition-duration:  $slowDuration;
                    transition-delay:  $fastDuration;
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            }
        }
        &--2 {
            position: relative;
            @for $i from 1 through 18 {
                $thisColor: nth($colorsList, rndNumber(3));
                $bgDots: append($bgDots, radial-gradient($thisColor, $thisColor 70%, transparent 71%), 'comma');

                $resultPosList: append($resultPosList, (rndNumber(100) * 1%) (rndNumber(100) * 1%), 'comma');
                $prevPosList: append($prevPosList, 50% 50%, 'comma');

                $randomSize: rndNumber(3) * 2%;
                $resultSizeList: append($resultSizeList, $randomSize $randomSize, 'comma');
                $prevSizeList: append($prevSizeList, .25em .25em, 'comma');
            }
            .rating__label {
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                .rating__label__icon {
                    fill: $coral;
                }
            }
            [type='radio'] {
                display: none;
                @for $j from 5 through 1 {
                    &:nth-of-type(#{$j}):checked ~ {
                        .rating__label {
                            .rating__label__icon {
                                fill: $white;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                &:first-of-type:checked + .rating__label:before {
                    background-size: $resultSizeList;
                    background-position: $resultPosList;
                    transition-duration:  $slowDuration;
                    transition-delay:  $fastDuration;
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you For your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://sass2css.herokuapp.com/ or http://www.sassmeister.com/

Those can be used to convert `scss` code to `CSS`

Comment: I got an error saying Undefined variable: "$fastDuration".

Comment: @Amal It means, you need some more .scss files, where it's defined.

Comment: The CodePen example you linked have included additional SCSS files that are likely used to define certain variables. Also, you can always go the CSS pane on CodePen and view the compiled CSS directly.

Comment: Thank you that helped me

Answer (score 0):

I you need compile only one file, you can use: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sass/try_sass.php
Otherwise you need sass gem (ruby library) to compile it. Read here for more details: http://sass-lang.com/install To not confuse you, sass gem supports .scss and .sass scss gem is not longer maintained.